# Using ly as my display manager and disabling gdm3?

Tags: ubuntu, display-manager

I'm currently on Ubuntu, using a virtual machine, and am trying to use ly as my display manager.Whenever I try to run `sudo systemctl ly.service` inside of the ly directory on my computer, I get an error. Would anyone know how to disable gdm3, which is the default display manager for Ubuntu?

Comment: What is the error? Your command above - `sudo systemctl ly.service` - won't do anything because you didn't give it an order; ex: start, stop, reload, enable, etc.

Comment: If you have successfully installed `ly` then [this may help](https://thelinuxuser.com/linux-display-managers/)